# linqtosql, timespan, aggregates ... can it be done?

Tags: linq

Can this be done w/ linqtosql?

```
SELECT City, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,StartDate,Completed)) AS Downtime
FROM Incidents
GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
```

---

```
db.Incidents
  .GroupBy(i => i.City)
  .Select(g => new
  {
    City = g.Key,
    DownTime = g.Sum(i => SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(i.StartDate, i.Completed))
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to use the SqlMethods class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx